# Get windows Log

Tags: windows, file, logging, find

I received a windows application that is create a file on my windows. How can I find out where the file is?
I guess the program create a text file to save a code or something. I want that file. What can I do and how can I find it?
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-at/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to monitor any changes to file system or registry a program makes. Filter for the name of your programs executable and for file creation. Then run your program and analyze the log. Be prepared there might be a lot of entries.

Also keep in mind that "codes" are often not just stored in files. It might be in the registry and it might not be in the format you expect...